Unable to mock CloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient()
I have a method which returns BlobResultSegment. I have to write unit test cases for the method. Can anyone please suggest any way to mock CloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient()
private async Task<BlobResultSegment> GetBlobResultSegment(string containerName, string prefix)
{
    **CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(_blobDataConnectionString)
                                                                .CreateCloudBlobClient();**

    var cc = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
    BlobResultSegment allBlobs = await cc.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(prefix, default);
    return allBlobs;
}


Your GetBlobResultSegment is a private method which indicates that you should not test it, otherwise, it should be protected or public.
However, if you absolutely need to test this method, let's consider what aspects we should focus on:
Your method calls an external library to get a BlobResultSegment and return it to the caller. Again, you shouldn't test the internal implementation details of the library.
The assertion for your method would be: I call an external library to get a BlobResultSegment, and I will receive anything that the external library returns to me.
Since I don't care how the library gets the BlobResultSegment, plus, it's going to be possible but tedious and provides no value to create mocks of CloudBlobClient, and CloudBlobContainer, I'm gonna extract every library calls to a virtual method:
public class BlobClientClass // Assuming this is the SUT that containning GetBlobResultSegment
{
    public async Task<BlobResultSegment> GetBlobResultSegment(string containerName, string prefix)
    {
        return await GetBlobResultSegmentInternal(containerName, prefix);
    }

    protected virtual async Task<BlobResultSegment> GetBlobResultSegmentInternal(string containerName, string prefix)
    {
        CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("")
        .CreateCloudBlobClient();

        var cc = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
        BlobResultSegment allBlobs = await cc.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(prefix, default);

        return allBlobs;
    }
}

Then in my test, I'll create a Test double to override the implementation of the call to the external library and return what I want for the test.
internal class TestableBlobClientClass : BlobClientClass
{
    private readonly BlobResultSegment blobResultSegment;

    public TestableBlobClientClass(BlobResultSegment blobResultSegment)
    {
        this.blobResultSegment = blobResultSegment;
    }
    protected override Task<BlobResultSegment> GetBlobResultSegmentInternal(string containerName, string prefix)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(blobResultSegment); 
    }
}

Finally, my test gonna assert what we've discussed above:
public class UnitTests2
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task Test1Async()
    {
        // Arrange

        var fakeResult = new BlobResultSegment(new List<CloudBlob>(), new BlobContinuationToken());

        var sut = new TestableBlobClientClass(fakeResult);

        // Act
        var result = await sut.GetBlobResultSegment("anyContainerName", "prefix");

        // Assert
        Assert.Equal(fakeResult, result);
    }
}

